# Spotify API key block / expires to fast

Tags: ajax, api, spotify

I've request a API key to get the users playlist. All my code works, but the only problem is that the key block or expires to fast. I use this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" + $("#gebruiker").val() + "/playlists",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + my key
    },
    Host: "api.spotify.com",
    Accept: "application/json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data){
        //code
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //code
    }
});
```

When blocks or expires the API key from Spotify and what can you do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens are deliberately set to expire after a short time, after which new tokens may be granted by supplying the refresh token originally obtained during the authorization code exchange. As explained in the https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/